# Excel SUMPRODUCT with multiple criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have been trying to get the SUM with multiple criteria for the below Territory IDs. They can have multiple Direct and POS records and the formula must be in B2 and C2 or the Manager Summary Sheet.

I have been trying to use SUMPRODUCT but I am receiving error values.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(('Account Mapping'!A2:A45130='Manager Summary'!$A2)*('Account Mapping'!B2:B45130='Manager Summary'!$B$1)*'Account Mapping'!C2:C45130)
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: You need to show what your current code is so people can suggest changes. Thanks

Comment: I just posted the code

Comment: `=SUMPRODUCT(('Account Mapping'!A2:A45130='Manager Summary'!$A2)*('Account Mapping'!B2:B45130='Manager Summary'!$B$1), 'Account Mapping'!C2:C45130)`

Comment: Did that work ?

Comment: No. Im still having issues

Comment: Like what? What error are you receiving?